# In Jenkins scripted pipeline getting Result from a job which was not directly triggered by the pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We have a Jenkins-Job (Job A) which pushes some artifacts to a git repository. This push triggers a different Jenkins-Job (Job B) which tests the newly pushed artifacts.

Job A sends a message which tells if everything was fine or if an error happened. But to have the information for the notification complete, Job A need to know at least if Job B was successful (having the log would be even better).

I now want to know if there is a possibility to retrieve the result of a finished job even if this job was not triggered by the job which needs the information?

Also is there a possibility to block Job A during Job B is running? I found the Block Build Plugin but this blocks a job only from starting until the specified jobs are finished.

Comment: I would totally change the triggering order: _User triggers JobA->Job Apush artifacts to git -> JobA triggers JobB and waits_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very strange setup. Looks like those should be stages not separate jobs. Still it's possible to get any job's status by using the jenkins json API

```
jenkins_url/job/${job_name}/lastBuild/api/json?tree=result,timestamp,estimatedDuration
```

Interesting question would be - how would you know which other job's number to check if those are triggered independently?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like this to get the results of the build? Have used it before to chain builds [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218554077-How-to-set-current-build-result-in-Pipeline-)

```
node {
try {
    // do something that fails
    sh "exit 1"
    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
} catch (Exception err) {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
```

}